# Null pointer exception using camera intent when getData called

Tags: android, null, camera, android-intent

I am using this tutorial / code to learn the camera functions: [cam tutorial.](http://develnetwork.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-take-full-size-picture-in.html)

The app is crashing after the camera Intent takes the picture and returns to `onActivityResult`.  But I am checking the make sure data is not null:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
System.out.println("***** inside onActivityResult");

  if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
    if (data != null) {
    System.out.println("***** inside data !=null if");

      imageid = data.getData().getLastPathSegment(); //returns full pic id
      System.out.println("***** imageid:" + imageid);
[...]
```

I get inside the `data != null` if statement and it crashes when I `imageid = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();`.

Logcat:

> 01-20 12:45:02.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-20 12:45:02.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {org.kimile/org.kimile.Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-20 12:45:02.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
>   01-20 12:45:02.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
>   01-20 12:45:02.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   01-20 12:45:02.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)

I can't figure out why its throwing the null exception even know I am checking to make sure its not null.

Comment: make sure you do an `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)` before you trying playing with the data returned from the Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is throwing a NullPointerException because the object returned from `data.getData()` is null. Thus when you call `getData().getLastPathSegment()`, the method `getLastPathSegment()` is being called on a null object - giving you your NPE.

Like **willytate** said, if you want to avoid the problem all together make sure you check the value of `resultCode`. Otherwise, make sure you check if `getData()` is null as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `data` is not null, `data.getData()` can still be null, and you can't call `getLastPathSegment()` on null. Maybe check that first, and *if* that's the case, maybe as @willytate commented, there is something wrong with the returned data?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the resultCode and requestCode avoiding them if null

`if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)`

Answer (score 0):

On returning after capturing image using camera intent sometimes it does not returns us data so that you have to use

```
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get(TAG_data);
```